# Cancel routing in Backbone because of unsaved data in form/model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got the following code. It produces a form with a simple text-field.

```
<div class="nav-bar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#showform">Click here for the form</a>
</div>

<div id="theform">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

After the user has entered some data, he clicks on the home-link. Backbone starts the navigation and calls the function for home.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "home": "home",
        "showform": "showtheform",
    },

    home: function() {
      if (current_view) {
        cuttent_view.remove();
      }

      current_view = new View_Home();
    },

    showtheform: function() {
      // Code to show the form
    }
});
```

After the Handler, the form is gone and the unsaved changes remain unsaved (but cannot be saved afterwards). Returning `false` in the router-function doesn't affect anything, the url still changes. How can I a) prevent the url from changing and b) asking the user if he wants to save the unsaved changes?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could bind a handler in the view and perform your logic prior to the router being fired. The benefit would be better encapsulation since validation is a concern for the view/model not the router

```
events: {
  "click a": "validateSave"
},
validateSave: function(){
  // check if we prompted to save already
  // if not return false and show a message;
}

// you can intercept other navigation events by guarding your routes like so.
...
someRoute: function() {
  if(this.savePrompt() { return; } 
  // show a different view
},
savePrompt: function() {
   if(!current_view.validateSave || !current_view.validateSave()) { return false; }
   if(this.history.length < 2) { return false; }

   // go back silently and replace last route in history
   this.navigate(this.history[this.history.length-2], {replace: true});

   return true;
}
```

Comment: The Nav-Bar is currently not part of the view. So its not affected by the Backbone.View events. That's the reason why I first wanted to add this functionality to the router. But I can bind non-view-DOM-elements via jQuery, so I'll try this way.

Comment: How is this supposed to handle if they navigate with the back button on their browser?

Comment: Added an example of how to use the same function in your router to guard back events.